# .Net Binary Serialization inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization

In a C# Context,  I have a Class B which is marked as Serializable and who's inheriting form a Class A who's not marked as this. Can i find a way to serialize instance of B without marking A as serializable?

Comment: I think you just need to implement iSerializable in Class B, this will allow you to control the serialization of the class.

Comment: If you want to serialize B you will have to serialize the state of it's superclass A as well. Why don't you want to mark A as Serializable?

Comment: A is a part of another project on wich i have no rights to edit

Answer (score 1):

Try using a serialization surrogate.  Nice [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx#S2) by Jeff Richter

Comment: Nice Mechanism. Thanks for the link, it's very interesting

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do *custom* serialization this should work - i.e. implement `ISerializable`. Not a nice option, though:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
class A {
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
class B : A, ISerializable {
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public B() { }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        info.AddValue("Foo", Foo);
        info.AddValue("Bar", Bar);
    }
    private B(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        Foo = info.GetInt32("Foo");
        Bar = info.GetString("Bar");
    }    
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        B b = new B { Foo = 123, Bar = "abc" }, clone;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            bf.Serialize(ms, b);
            ms.Position = 0;
            clone = (B)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(clone.Foo);
        Console.WriteLine(clone.Bar);
    }
}
```

Do you just want to store the data? I can also think of a way to do this using protobuf-net (rather than `BinaryFormatter`, which I assume you are using).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, exactely, i'am using BynaryFormatter. The need is to store the object's data. About protobuf-net, what's the advantages of using it instead of BinaryFormatter? is there any examples?

Comment: a: faster and smaller (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance) b: platform/language independent (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) c: not metadata specific (can rename fields, move/rename types, etc: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html). Brief intro: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: Note that the intro doesn't cover inheritance, and the inheritance support in protobuf-net is a customisation and won't map *directly* to Java/C++/etc: they'll see the data, but not as inheritance (hey, I didn't design the wire format...)

Comment: A small potential gotcha: You may want to mark the base class A as sealed if possible in case someone later on implemented a custom serialiser on it. This would then break the serialisation on B.